# Gradle build errors after updating Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, build.gradle

I just updated Android Studio, and now when I try to build my app, I get the following Gradle error:

> ```
> Information: Compilation completed with 2 errors and 0 warnings in 28 sec
> Information: 2 errors
> Information: 0 warnings
> Error: Gradle: : java.lang.NullPointerException
> /Users/mhuggins/Sites/SmoothieFlow/build.gradle
>     Error:(9, 0) Gradle: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'SmoothieFlow'.
>                  > The SDK directory '/Users/mhuggins/Library/Caches/AndroidStudioPreview/compile-server/"/Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk"' does not exist.
> ```

Details about Android Studio version:

> Android Studio (I/O Preview) AI-130.709792
>
> Build #AI-130.709792, built on June 14, 2013
>
> JDK 1.6.0_43
>
> VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM by Apple Inc.

Does anyone know why I'm getting this and what I can do to fix it?

Comment: Try setting ANDROID_HOME env variable point to your SDK root. I'm not sure if this will help though. It helped me but the problem was different.

Comment: Seems to be some misconfiguration to SDK references. Click on **SDK Manager** in Android Studio toolbar and check if all the references are correct.

Comment: Looks like I'm not the only one getting this: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=56628

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Try adding a new file in the root of your project called "local.properties" (or modify the existing one). It should contain

```
sdk.dir=
```

followed by the path to the sdk location, in my case

```
sdk.dir=/Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk
```

I think Android Studio normally creates one automatically but says that it shouldn't be added to VCS. I put it in my .gitignore and cloned the project on my Mac which resulted in this error. Strangely before 0.1.5 it worked just fine without the file.

Comment: For project with multiple modules, check that the file is at the root of the project: it seems it is not picked up if it is in the module folder (as it was if migrating from Eclipse)

Comment: Cool. I had the same problem too. Having a `local.properties` local settings pointing to the `sdk.dir` solves it.

Comment: According to the bug tracker, this has been fixed in the code for a future release. https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/61320/

Comment: can we use a environment or a gradle variable here rather than hard-coding it?

Comment: I had this same issue, but with "ndk.dir". This worked for me! Thanks!

Comment: path should be where your SDK is, for me it was /opt/android-sdk

Comment: Adding this file to an Eclipse ADT project root folder, fixed the issue as well - Thanks!

Comment: It's already took default by IDE in my case, but still same issue. Any suggestion!

Comment: In my case, I had just recently removed the android NDK but the ndk line in my `local.properties` file was still present and caused my build to fail.

Answer (score 9):

i have had the Same issue with running Android-Studio on windows XP. After the Update it kept giving me the same error of `Gradle: A problem occurred evaluating root project`. so what i had to do is:

1- make sure you know where your android studio directory is in my case it was 
`C:\Documents and Settings\UserName\Local Settings\Application Data\Android\android-studio\sdk`

2- open the project root directory

3- locate the local.properties file and open it in a text editor notepad did it for me

4- change the sdk.dir="add your SDK directory here without the quotations" and make sure you use double instead of one on each separator 
`sdk.dir=C:\\\Documents and Settings\\\UserName\\\Local Settings\\\Application Data\\\Android\\\android-studio\\\sdk`

5- Rebuild your project

That was the only way it worked for me

Comment: Thanks for this step-by-step explanation. It's the same solution as the one from buddahbrot, but following your steps finally got it going. Thanks =)

Comment: Instead of double backslashes you can also use forward slashes. It said to be fixed here [https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/62585/] but it's still present in the newest version (0.2.5)

Comment: I'm a bit confused; Why are there **triple** backslashes up here and it states to use **double** backslashes? :/

Answer (score 7):

For me the problem was that in OS X, I need set my `ANDROID_HOME` to a full path, such as:

```
export ANDROID_HOME="/Users/username/Development/android-sdk-macosx"
```

When using the user directory shorthand (`~`) Gradle seems to consider it a relative directory.

Comment: I experienced the same behavior on Ubuntu. `~/Android/Sdk` was getting expanded to `/home/hillshum/android-studio/~/Android/Sdk` or something resembling that

Answer (score 2):

//according to my android studio project folder

just go into local file and open it into notepad then include the following line according to your project sdk file

sdk.dir=C\:/Users/raj/AppData/Local/Android/android-studio/sdk
//

Answer (score 2):

As for me `ANDROID_HOME` didn't work. It shows error that path is not found/exists which is totally stupid. Also I tried to create `local.properties` with `sdk.dir=D:/android/sdk` - this also wont work with the same error saying this path does not exist. What helped me - a RELATIVE PATH, so when I set

```
sdk.dir=../../../android/sdk
```

it starts to work

Answer (score 1):

For those who are confused by:
  "This file is automatically generated by Android Studio. # Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!"
  when they open local.properties :

It works anyway, if the file is overridden, just change it again.

To easily find the location of your sdk, try:
  File -> Project Structure -> Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, because my office PC is 32-bit and my home PC is 64 bit.
In the `local.properties` file, I changed

> sdk.dir=C:/Program Files/Android/android-studio/sdk

to

> sdk.dir=C:/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-studio1/sdk

note the **x86** version of Program Files

Answer (score 0):

Took me forever to find it but this was fixed with buddahbrot's suggestion of creating a local.properties file in the root of your project folder to include sdk.dir= followed by the path to the sdk location.

This worked fine before with just ANDROID_HOME set in Windows but in OSX, I needed to specify with sdk.dir.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is the local.properties file is incorrect.

Check in the root folder and app folder for local.properties and make sure they point to the SDK folder. **Both** files must point to the SDK folder for this to work.

sdk.dir=C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

Answer (score 0):

This works for me to get rid of "Try Again" on the top about Gradle errors.

```
File >> Project Structure >> Project >> Android Gradle Plugin Version = 3.2.1 and Gradle Version 5.1.1 >> Ok >> Apply

Android Studio >> Build >> Make Project
```

You may get fine, but it will pop-up again for "Update Gradle" I choose "Do not remind me for this project"

Answer (score -1):

according to my android studio project folder

just go into local file and open it into notepad then include the following line according to your project sdk file

```
sdk.dir=C\:/Users/raj/AppData/Local/Android/android-studio/sdk //
```