# Cannot find SDK location

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

After downloading the latest update of Android Studio Beta. I am receiving errors such as the following:

```
3:07:53 PM ProcessNotCreatedException: Cannot run program "/Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/tools/android": error=2, No such file or directory: Cannot run program "/Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/tools/android": error=2, No such file or directory
```

[image]

[image]

The problem is that I am unable to find out what to put in SDK Location.
[image]

So I am stuck because I cannot even open new projects, compile, build, open SDK manager etc.

My local.properties is:

```
## This file is automatically generated by Android Studio.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file should *NOT* be checked into Version Control Systems,
# as it contains information specific to your local configuration.
#
# Location of the SDK. This is only used by Gradle.
# For customization when using a Version Control System, please read the
# header note.
sdk.dir=/Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk
```

I am unsure how to resolve this error. I have been following the information I found here, but no luck:

[Android Studio - SDK is out of date or is missing templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16575988/android-studio-sdk-is-out-of-date-or-is-missing-templates)

[Gradle build errors after updating Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17125175/gradle-build-errors-after-updating-android-studio)

Comment: Do you have a standalone SDK intsalled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been using Android Studio for some time now and haven't tried to install fresh with just the Beta version which is supposed to include the SDK now. Since it didn't seem to install with your Android Studio Beta installation, you can try installing it separately. Go [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) and click on "GET THE SDK FOR AN EXISTING IDE". One advantage is this allows you a little more control and you will know exactly where the SDK is installed.

Comment: Okay I downloaded it but where exactly in this file do I set the SDK location

Comment: @XiJiaopin Install it and point Android Studio to the location where you install it.

Comment: Btw do you know how to fix ....Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 11 cannot be smaller than version L

Comment: @XiJiaopin Change `minSdkVersion` from `11` to `'L'`.

Comment: You sir, helped me a lot here you go

Comment: btw one more lil question do you know how to resolve Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]

Comment: @XiJiaopin Please do a google search and if you cannot find anything post a new question.

Comment: Okay http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24546249/failure-install-failed-older-sdk-error-from-manifest-merger-failed-uses-sdk

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem today. After installation of Android Studio 1, it won't find the SDK and throw the same error. I was expecting a wizard which will automatically download the SDK but there wasn't. I cleaned ~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio and relaunched AndroidStudio. That's when the SDK installation wizards came up and installed the SDK. 
[image]